# Is there a difference between "tkinter-variable" tkinter methods arguments and string tkinter methods arguments?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know if there is any difference between something like tkinter.DISABLED and 'disabled', or tkinter.ALL and 'all'.

So I wanted to clear my tkinter canvas like this:

```
canvas0.delete('all')
```

But then I tried:

```
canvas0.delete(tkinter.ALL)
```

And it worked the same, so is there ANY difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter defines a number of constants, one of which is `tkinter.ALL = 'all'`

So they are essentially the same.